# Extjs tabpanel with big complex objects or dynamically loaded objects

Tags: object, extjs, extjs4

I have some problem with complex objects on tabpanel.
I have 2 complex objects with stores, windows, grids, trees and etc. Here is the beginning of the object:

```
Ext.define('Ext.app.DocumentsContainer', {

    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',   

    initComponent: function(){

        var documentsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
```

And I have tabpanel with 2 panels(one for each object).
full code of viewport with tabpanel:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        padding: '5',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'north',
                height: 50
            },
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                region: 'center',
                width: 100,
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Documents',
                    layout: 'border',
                    items: Ext.create('Ext.app.DocumentsContainer'),
                },{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Transmittals',
                    layout: 'border',
                    items: [Ext.create('Ext.app.TransmittalsContainer')],
                }]
            }
        ],
    });
```

When I testing my page, a have a problem, because somehow data from one object dysplays in grid in another object, or doesnt dysplay at all.
But both objects working correctly one at a time.
I think, I can fix it by dynamically loading objects when tab is opened, but dont know how can I do it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the internals of your two components `Ext.app.DocumentsContainer` and `Ext.app.TransmittalsContainer` one cannot reliably answer your question. Perhaps you assign the same ID to two different internal components - that's most often the reason for mixed up data.

Secondly, [Frederic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688853/extjs-tabpanel-with-big-complex-objects-or-dynamically-loaded-objects/6689739#6689739) is right - you're overnesting your components. Both panels inside the `tabpanel` are unnecessary because you can put your components directly into the `tabpanel` as illustrated by [Frederic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688853/extjs-tabpanel-with-big-complex-objects-or-dynamically-loaded-objects/6689739#6689739). However, if you insist to keep your panels, try changing the `layout` to `fit` because that layout-type handles single-item-components (sized the single component to fit into the parent frame).

Comment: Second day i'm trying to find double `id`, but only for checking after your post I've founded it :) it was just about tenth checking :)

Answer (score 2):

You are overnesting the tabpanel. The tabpanels items will automatically stretch their content. So it might just work for you.

Do this instead. Change DocumentContainer to pe panel (so it can have a title. )

```
Ext.define('Ext.app.DocumentsContainer', {

    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',   

    initComponent: function(){

        var documentsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
```

And change you tabpanel to this. I also deleted the width on your center region. center regions fills out the rest of the border layouts space automatically.

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        padding: '5',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'north',
                height: 50
            },
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                region: 'center',
                items: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.app.DocumentsContainer', {title:'Documents'}),
                    Ext.create('Ext.app.TransmittalsContainer', {title:'Transmittals'})
                ]
            }
        ],
    });
```

Also. as Stefan mentioned. Never ever use id´s in your ExtJS4 code. They are evil and will freck your result up eventually. itemId or just simple Ext.DomQuery is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've changed 'Container' to `Panel` and it saved to me one nesting level. And yes, 'id' is Evil :)